# Layer synchronizeWithRemoteNotification not getting called in iOS

Tags: ios, push-notification

I'm building an iOS app and making use of layer.
According to the documentation, when a push notification for a message comes in, you should not immediately switch to the conversation because the message might not have finished synching. So you call a synchronise method and pass it a completion function as follows:

```
self.layerClient!.synchronizeWithRemoteNotification(userInfo, completion: { (conversation, message, error) in

    if (conversation != nil || message != nil) {

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(CXOConstants.Notifications.BadgeChatTabNotification.rawValue, object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)

        let msgPart = message?.parts.first
        if msgPart?.MIMEType == "text/plain"{
            let msgText = String(data: msgPart!.data!,encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            debugPrint("msgText:: \(msgText)")
        } else {
            debugPrint("The user sent an image")
        }
        completionHandler(.NewData)
    } else {
        completionHandler(.Failed)
    }
})
```

Problem is, this method never gets called. I have tried implementing the same logic outside of the `synchronizeWithRemoteNotification` method, but when I switch to the conversation, it takes a couple seconds for the message to appear in the conversation.

Could use some help here figuring out why the method isn't getting called.
Thanks :)

Comment: I'm having the same issue - completion block is never called when this method is executed. Also, the layer documentation says to set this method equal to a BOOL, and that always returns false.
    Doc: https://github.com/layerhq/documentation/blob/master/ios/guides/push-integration.md